Failed to get PTS from live audio stream with ffmpeg in Linux
I am working on audio playing in Linux with ffmpeg-4.4.4.
Now I found sometimes the PTS in the live audio stream is 0, which caused failure of calculating current position when playing the stream (.m3u8).
Here is the code logics.
void stream_main(void)
{
    packet = av_packet_alloc();
    pframe = av_frame_alloc();

    while (1) {
        if (av_read_frame(pfmtctx, packet) < 0) {
            avcodec_flush_buffers(pcodectx);
            break;
        }
        if (packet->stream_index != audio_stream) {
            continue;
        }

        if (player_ctrl == PLAYER_PAUSE) {
            // PAUSE playing media completely;
            break;
        }
        /* If it is resumed from pause_s */
        if (pause_s > 0.10) {
            if (0 == avformat_seek_file(pfmtctx, -1, INT64_MIN, pause_s * AV_TIME_BASE, INT64_MAX, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY | AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD)) {
                avcodec_flush_buffers(pcodectx);
                pause_s = 0.0;
                continue;
            }
        }

    printf("======== pts: %lld, curr_sec: %lld\n", packet->pts, current_sec);
        decode_and_play_frame(packet, frame);
        av_packet_unref(packet);
    }

    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&packet);
    avcodec_close(pcodectx);
    avformat_close_input(pfmtctx);
    avformat_network_deinit();
}    

So here are the questions.

Is it right for PTS is 0 in packet of ffmpeg in live audio stream?
If it is expected, how can I get/calculate the current playing position from the packet or frame?
How to check if a live-stream(online stream) is seekable or not? What I did is checking if stream's start_time is AV_NOPTS_VALUE, if so, I will take this stream as non-seekable, is my way reliable to check if the stream is seekable?


By testing the codes, I found where the 0 of PTS came from.
The PTS of packet will be 0 when pause_s is non-zero, and avformat_seek_file is called with it.
I don't know why, but without calling avformat_seek_file with non-zero pause_s for live-stream, the PTS of packet will be normal.
That is why I need to find a concrete way to know if the stream is seekable or not, since I want to support both offline and online media. offline media seems to be seekable, but online media does NOT.
